# How to stay MVC and have dynamic partials calls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view, model, partials

I was wondering if it was correct to do the following in the model:

```
get_partial
    #logic...
      return "_partial_name1"
    #more logic
      return  "_partial_name2"
    #more logic
      return  "_partial_name3"
    else
      "_partial_name4"
    end
end
```

and in the view :

```
<%= render @product.get_partial %>
```

There is NO erb code in the model, only logic choosing wich partial it should display.
I tested it and it works, but I wanted to know if it is correct from an MVC point of view. If not, where should this logic be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should never care what view to render, ever.

If you need logic in deciding what to do, use a view helper.

Answer (score 1):

In the view, I think you can just put the if..else logic there..  You wouldn't want to put this logic in the model either way.  Perhaps you meant controller, but I think putting it in the view is the best way

```
<% if (condition) %>
    <%= render 'partial1' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'partial2' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: My logic is a little bit more complicated, but following you i should do switch (@product.partial_logic) case 1 case2 case 3 ... ? Isn't it the same thing with more code in the end?

Comment: Switch or if/else, essentially the same.  Partials are used in views only, so they should not have a reference to them in a model or controller as Karpie said above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems the best course of action would be to use helpers. I will do that.